Optimal Bath Fan Location
Trying to decide on placement of bathroom exhaust fan. Primary purpose/concern is moisture from shower. Bathroom is 7'x10' and I've purchased a 110CFM Panasonic Whisper. It says it's rated for "in shower" use. Current fan is in the center of the room, however, if it's optimal to be in the shower I can move the hole. Fixtures include: toilet, shower (no tub), and sink. Any strong opinions for inside or outside shower?


The fan creates air flow through the bathroom.  Air enters from somewhere, and exits through the fan to the outside.  The entry point is usually the door but it might be a window if you generally leave a window open.   The fan should be as far as possible from the entry point.  This will maximize the exchange of air through the entire room and minimize dead spots.

The fan should not be very near the entry point.

The fan should not be in the shower.  If you run it while using the shower it will make you feel colder.  If a little humidity stays inside the shower after you're done with it, it doesn't matter.  If humidity leaves the shower and enters the room, see point 1.


This all assumes you get to choose where it goes.  Sometimes, access for the duct to an exterior wall is limited, and you have to place the fan accordingly.

If keeping a mirror clear is a goal, you want the mirror as close to the entry point as possible, and the fan both as close to the shower as possible and as far from the entry.  Whether you feel a draught in the shower depends on the layout.  With a door from floor to above head height, you don't.  With a walk-in shower you do a little, but it's spread out.  The worst case is a door or curtain with a gap at the bottom - cold ankles

3a. Putting the fan in the shower will require you to GFCI-ize the circuit, if it isn't already.

@jay613 Greatly appreciate the thorough feedback. Regarding point #2 it's probably worth me mentioning the layout. When you walk into the bathroom, the fan is currently centered in the room straight ahead. Shower will be off to the far-right corner. There's also a furnace vent on the floor (against the wall) opposite of the doorway (therefore next to the shower). This is not an intake. With all that in mind,  sounds like moving it slightly closer to the shower and away from both sources of airflow (while staying out of the shower), if I'm following your advice correctly.

Given that you have ducting (hopefully 4” or bigger) and a hole in the ceiling, put the new one where the old one was.
There might be a fractional improvement pulling air right above the shower, but I really doubt that it makes much of a difference.

The location of the fan really doesn't matter. The goal of your fan is to take warm, humid air from the ceiling and vent it outside to reduce humidity. This is necessary to limit the growth of mold. It wouldn't be ideal to have it in a corner for air movement reasons, but it would still work. It will still lower the pressure of the room slightly to pull cooler and dryer air in.
I wouldn't suggest over-the-shower. There's two problems with that

Assuming you're vented outside, even with an insulated vent line you're inviting condensation to build during the winter and drip cold water on whomever is taking a shower.
While unlikely, overzealous kids can get water on the ceiling of your shower sometimes. You probably don't want water in your fan itself. Having it outside makes this even less likely to happen.

I should note something important here: your 110 CFM fan almost certainly has a 6" duct line. Your old ducts may be 4". Be prepared to upsize the ductwork.

appreciate the thoughtful reply. All valid points. Sounds like moving slightly closer to where the new shower will be, while remaining outside of it, is optimal. Being a relatively small room (70sqft) this may be a non-issue, but I wanted to give it adequate thought.
I believe the 110CFM Remodel allows 4" or 6" but I'll be running new ductwork regardless, as old fan was previously venting to attic...
